# Dynamic fill of a rdlc

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I have write this code :

```
namespace ImportarAlamo
{
    public partial class RelIndi : Form
    {
        public RelIndi()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void RelIndi_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            reportViewer1.Visible = false;
        }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        reportViewer1.Visible = true;
        reportViewer1.Reset();
        fillrel();

        // Here is the part to populate the report :
        ReportDataSource DS = new ReportDataSource("individual2",fillrel());
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"C:\relatorios\Report8.rdlc";
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(DS); 
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh(); 

    }

    public DataSet fillrel()
    {
        DataSet uny = new DataSet();

        SqlConnection abre = Tconex.GetConnection();
        SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand llena = new SqlCommand("rel_Noparam", abre);
        llena.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        da2.SelectCommand = llena;
        da2.Fill(uny,"rel");
        abre.Close();
        return uny;
    }
```

The report8.rdlc have nothing, now the code have no error , but can i put a tablix on the report, how i show the fields???

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the datasource to the collection:

```
ReportDataSource DS = new ReportDataSource("individual2",fillrel());
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(DS);
```

Comment: What do you mean with **populate**? the code *here is the part to populate the report...* is all you need

Comment: Oh I see you edit. You don't designed your report yet? If you don't, look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934258(v=sql.100).aspx